# Find the maximum delta of a field between date A and date B

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been noodling around with an aggregation for hours now trying to work out how to do this without writing code and walking the collection. There are millions of documents in this collection, so I'd prefer to write an aggregation than walk the entire collection and brute force a result, but I am officially stumped. I am a newbie to MongoDB and aggregations in particular, so please be gentle. I do want to learn, so I'd also appreciate pointers to tutorials or similar to help me improve.

We have a collection that includes `updated_at`, which is when a document was created, `faction_name` or `faction_id`, and `system` name or `system_id`, and `influence`. I am trying to create a sorted aggregation that will list the top faction influence delta changes between two `updated_at` dates (date A, such as today, and date B, such as yesterday) in the same system and faction. I'd like the output to contain the faction id or name and system id or name, and delta of the two influence values. `influence_delta` would be a computed value from the difference of two documents, and influence movement can result in a positive or negative change. We believe the largest single day change is 0.075 and the smallest is -0.075.

Basically, I'm trying to create a table in a web app that will display the biggest influence changes between date A and date B, but the system_id and faction_id need to be the same.

| system_id | faction_id | influence_delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 605e573a68ad125bce5186b4 | 605e573a68ad125bce5186bd | 0.075 |
| 605e573a68ad125bce51868d | 605e573a68ad125bce518696 | 0.031 |
| 605e573a68... | 605e573a68ad... | 0.021 |

Here's a sample document. There will be at least one document per day for popular systems, and for less popular systems, it could be weeks since a document was last recorded. For each system and faction, there be the same faction_id and system_id values as long as the faction has not arrived recently or retreated (this is Elite Dangerous), and there will be different `influence` values. Stored `influence` values range from 0.0 to 1.0. I would suggest for performance, please consider using `system_id` and `faction_id`, which are unique and indexed, rather than the system or faction name.

```json
 {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "605e573bbfcfe2a2cdb7fefb"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "$date": "2021-03-26T21:50:50.000Z"
    },
    "updated_by": "EDDN",
    "system": "Gliese 875",
    "system_lower": "gliese 875",
    "system_id": {
      "$oid": "605e573a68ad125bce5186b4"
    },
    "faction_id": {
      "$oid": "605e573a68ad125bce5186bd"
    },
    "faction_name": "Gliese 875 Allied Exchange",
    "faction_name_lower": "gliese 875 allied exchange",
    "state": "none",
    "influence": 0.039715,
    "happiness": "$faction_happinessband2;",
    "active_states": [],
    "pending_states": [],
    "recovering_states": [],
    "conflicts": [],
    "systems": [
      {
        "system_id": {
          "$oid": "605e573a68ad125bce5186b4"
        },
        "name": "Gliese 875",
        "name_lower": "gliese 875"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
```